# Filter WP_List_Table result

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to filter the results of the `Media Library` page to only display files of X type.

I traced the origin of the table to the `WP_Media_List_Table` class  and is being called by `$wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Media_List_Table');` `$wp_list_table->display();`

Now `display()` output is full formated HTML and I want to only display files that are of type `PNG`. Is there a way to display only PNG files in the table view?

[image]